# When using timeit() method "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" raised. How to correct it

Tags: python

I want to devise an experiment that compares the performance of the del operator on lists and dictionaries. Below is my code. Except the timeit parts, the rest code runs correctly. What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
import timeit
import random

for n in range(10, 20):
    ls = list(range(n))
    dic = {j: None for j in ls}
    r = random.randrange(len(ls))
    del dic[r]
    del ls[r]
    print(ls)
    print(dic)

    x1 = timeit.Timer("del ls[r]", "from __main__ import ls, r")
    x2 = timeit.Timer("del dic[r]", "from __main__ import dic, r")
    print(f'{r}:{x1.timeit()}--{x2.timeit()}')
```

---

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
{0: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8:     None, 9: None}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zheng/Work/Big O problem.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(f'{r}:{x1.timeit()}--{x2.timeit()}')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib    /python3.6/timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already deleted element dic[r] and ls[r] earlier in the loop, when you run x1.timeit() and x2.timeit(), it would give an error as dic[r] and ls[r] has already been deleted.

Consider the following working code

```
import timeit
import random

for n in range(10, 20):
    ls = list(range(n))
    dic = {j: None for j in ls}
    x1 = timeit.Timer("del ls[random.randrange(len(ls))]", "from __main__ import random,ls")   # delete random
    x2 = timeit.Timer("del dic[random.choice(dic.keys())]", "from __main__ import random,dic")
    print(x1.timeit(n) - x2.timeit(n)) # Will work for numbers upto n
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much.
I just run the code you upload. Same error happened again. 

   IndexError: list assignment index out of range..

BTW, these four statements can be omitted.
    del dic[r]
    del ls[r]
    print(ls)
    print(dic)

Comment: The code should work. I have modified the code a bit to make it more readable.

Comment: So much thanks, Daniel! It works now.
I have three questions.
1, You use random.choice for dic but not random.range. What's the difference?
2, Why import random module again in the timeit parts since we have import it in the beginning?
3, Could you tell me what's wrong with my former code...I still haven't understand where the error "list assignment index out of range" raised from? 
Thank you so much!!

Comment: Sorry, I run your code again and some Error happens. Here is the information:
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: I found the answer. In python 3, the object returned by dic.keys() is not a list but a range. So there needs to adding a list() to the statement:
    del dic[random.choice(list(dic.keys()))]
It works now. No "support indexing Error".
Thanks, Daniel!